# Adding Column To Table In Sql Server Take Long Time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to add a new column to a Sql Server table with about 20,000 rows using this query

```
ALTER TABLE [db].[dbo].[table] 
ADD entry_date date;
```

the query result still working, until now it takes 10 minute and still working, Is it normal !

Comment: The operation requires exclusive access to the table. Perhaps the operation is blocked by other activity. Run `sp_who2` to check for blocking.

Answer (score 2):

10 minutes seems like a long time, but adding a column takes time.

Why?  Adding a column (generally) requires changing the layout of the table on the pages where the data is stored.  In your case, the entry date is 4 bytes, so every row needs to be expanded by 4 bytes -- and fit on one data page.

Adding columns generally requires rewriting all data.

Also note that while this is occurring, locks and transactions are also involved.  So, if other activity on the server is accessing the table (particularly data changes), then that also affects performance.

Oh, did I mention that indexes are involved as well?  Indexes care about the physical location of data.

All that said, 10 minutes seems like a long time for 20,000 rows.  You might find that things go much faster if you do:

- Create a new table with the columns you want -- but no indexes except for the primary key or clustered index.
- Insert the data from the existing table.
- Add whatever indexes and triggers you want.

Of course, you need to be careful if you have an `identity` column.

Comment: Thanks, I found that there is an activity on another server used the table that I want to add a field to it :) Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to add column to a small local database. I only succeeded when I stopped running the app that uses the database. It was a flask-Python app in my case.